# Run a sub from another module in Office 2010?

Tags: vba, module, ms-word

In Word 2003 I use:

```
        Call modulename.subname(passvar)
```

In Word 2010 it gives me a run time error 13 error type mismatch?  Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

It's likely that in your Sub `subname` you specify a type of an argument for it to expect, and your `passvar` doesn't match that type (probably because you haven't declared it and it's passed as an `Object`)

Comment: Figured this out two minutes after posting!  :S  I didn't update the sub in my 2010 version like I had done in the 2003 version.  Thanks!